# How to deal with expensive fixture/factory_girl object creation in tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

For all users in our system, we generate a private/public key pair, which often takes a second or two.  That's not a deal breaker on the live site, but it makes running the tests extremely slow, and slow tests won't get run.

Our setup is Rails 3.1 with factory_girl and rspec.

I tried creating (10 or so) some ahead of time with a method to return a random one, but this seems to be problematic: perhaps they're getting cleared out of the database and are unavailable for subsequent tests... I'm not sure.

This might be useful: https://github.com/pcreux/rspec-set - any other ideas?

Comment: you could try loading those data via fixtures or why not use a "fake" private/public key pair?

Comment: It turns out that rspec-set was enough for our needs.  The only drawback is having to clean up after it, but at least the tests are fast.

Comment: You can use databasecleaner to clean up your database after you've run your tests
https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/pcreux/rspec-set was good enough for what we need, combined with an after/all block to clean up after the droppings it leaves in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a fake key pair for your tests. Pregenerating them won't work, at least not if you store them in the DB, because the DB should get cleared for every test. I suppose you could store them in a YAML file or something and read them from there...